# Why are the values empty in a Hash after inserting an array?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of numbers where I want the individual numbers to be the key and the array itself to be the value. Doing this poses no problems

```
keys.each do |i| 
    myHash[i] = keys
end
```

But now I want the values to be the array minus the first value for every subsequent iteration so I did this

```
keys = Array.new

numbers.each do |i|
    keys.push(i)
end

keys.each do |i|
    # puts i
    # puts numbers.inspect
    myHash[i] = numbers
    numbers.shift
end
```

And it gives me empty arrays as the values in my hash for all the keys. Why is that? Ultimately, I want my hash to look like this given an array of [1, 2, 3, 4]

{1=>[1, 2, 3, 4], 2=>[2, 3, 4], 3=>[3, 4], 4=>[4]}

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing a deep copy of the array.

Try :

```
keys.each do |i|
   # puts i
   # puts numbers.inspect
   myHash[i] = numbers.clone
   numbers.shift
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check this after the 10 minutes is up!